# How do I use a SDK for creating C# programs?

Tags: c#, .net, api, sdk

My company uses a software called GlobalCapture from square9. It's basically for OCR scanning and making workflows. They have a set of APIs and an SDK for doing various things. They have one option to create your own custom node in your workflows.

I'm trying to use C# (most of their example code is written in C# on their GitHub) to create a custom node that takes a PDF and converts it into a JPG (a whole other problem that I'm trying to figure out) But, I've spent hours looking at their documentation trying to create even a single program with it.

I'm not asking for anyone to straight up solve my problem. More or less, I really need someone to help me point me in the right direction and tell me what I need to learn to make this all work.

These are the docs & info that I'm using :

https://github.com/Square9Softworks/custom-workflow-nodes (example code of custom nodes in C#)

http://knowledge.square-9.com:8090/display/CN/Custom+Nodes

http://knowledge.square-9.com:8090/display/CN/Square9.CustomNode+SDK

http://www.square-9.com/api/

And here is my code thus far :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Square9.CustomNode;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Syncfusion.Pdf.Parsing;
using Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.PdfViewer;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace ConvertDocument
{
public class Convert : CaptureNode
{
    public override void Run()
    {
        
 
        var pagePath = Process.Document.GetPage(0);
        Process.Document.AddPage(pagePath);
        LogHistory("Custom Node Test");

        
        /*
        PdfViewerControl pdfViewer = new PdfViewerControl();
        PdfLoadedDocument loadedDocument = new PdfLoadedDocument(pagePath);
        pdfViewer.Load(loadedDocument);
        Bitmap image = pdfViewer.ExportAsImage(0);
        */

      }
   }
}
```

The commented out code is suppose to convert a PDF to a JPG using a library called syncfusion. The three lines in my Run() function are me trying to see if I can add text to the history tab and add a page to a document going through.

But , I keep getting this error on square9 in their webapp:
"An exception was thrown inside the CaptureNode class: The method or operation is not implemented."

What do I need to learn to make this all work? I'm still new to C# but, I really want to mess around with this SDK. I am just so confused on where to go.

Comment: You need to determine which line of your code is causing the error. Set a break point in the first line of the Run() method and step through the code. Check the value each variable and make sure it's valid. Maybe, for example, Process.Document.GetPage(0) is returning null, which is causing an error when you pass it to the Process.Document.AddPage() method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out what I was doing wrong. I forgot to build my projects .dll file and upload the file in their webapp. I am still new to c# so this was very confusing but, I figured it out!

Comment: Feels good, huh? Careful, problem solving can be very addictive.